# Buck with input feedback?

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, buck, feedback

I made a ZCS buck converter for the following specifications:

12 V to 5 V, 50W, 200 kHz switching frequency.

But in reality, the source might not be 12 V always, and may have fluctuations. Is there any way to address this problem? Something like sensing the input voltage and adding associated control (I know it is the output that is "fed back" to get the required output)? Initially I thought this could be addressed by current-mode control, but I am not sure it pertains to the fluctuating source issue.

Comment: I like to use a comparator or op amp to compare the output voltage to a reference.  If the output is lower than it should be, the op amp charges a capacitor, and if the voltage is higher it discharges.  The voltage on the capacitor sets the duty cycle of the buck converter.  It's very primitive but it auto adjusts to the load.  I like to make it drop the voltage faster than it raises it to prevent spikes.

Comment: Usually, you just sense on the output and the controller will adjust accordingly, but if you need to speed up the response due to changes on input voltage, the search term is _feed forward_.

Comment: Ooops I missed that you already had feedback.  As long as your voltage reference is stable to input voltage fluctuations you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The closed control loop for the output voltage handles that. Adding another control loop which works on the same target will not improve anything but create a very near pole and the system may hop from one stability region to the other at random and thus, become meta-instable.

You need enough inductivity headroom to handle the largest voltage spread. That's all.